# ktor execute jar file

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I want make a jar file from my ktor project.

here is my `main` function

```
import io.ktor.server.engine.*
import io.ktor.server.netty.*
import io.ktor.server.application.*
import io.ktor.server.response.*
import io.ktor.server.routing.*

fun main() {
embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080, host = "0.0.0.0") {
    routing {
        get("/") {
            call.respondText("Hello World!")
        }
      }
   }.start(wait = true)
}
```

and here is my `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
id 'application'
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.6.20'
}

group "com.example"
version "0.0.1"
mainClassName = "com.example.ApplicationKt"

def isDevelopment = project.ext.has("development")
applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-Dio.ktor.development=$isDevelopment"]

application {
mainClass.set("io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain")
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven { url "https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/ktor/eap" }
}

dependencies {
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-server-core-jvm:$ktor_version"
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-server-netty-jvm:$ktor_version"
implementation "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:$logback_version"
testImplementation "io.ktor:ktor-server-tests-jvm:$ktor_version"
testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version"
}
```

and here is my `settings.gradle`

```
rootProject.name = "ktor-sample"
```

when I try to run `./gradlew :ktor-sample:installDist` I get this error

- What went wrong:
  Project 'ktor-sample' not found in root project 'ktor-sample'.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I need to create a .jar of a ktor project I usually add this to the build.gradle.kts

```kotlin
val compileKotlin: KotlinCompile by tasks
compileKotlin.kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

val compileTestKotlin: KotlinCompile by tasks
compileTestKotlin.kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

and after running the following on terminal

```
gradlew stage
```

a .jar is then created in the `build/libs/project.jar`.

Comment: If you are unsure, you should ask a clarification question. For that you need the privilege for commenting (in just a few reputation increases...). https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead If you cannot answer without asking please delete this.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you don't have a subproject named `ktor-sample` so just run `./gradlew installDist`.